# Do I always need isset inside an if?

Tags: smarty, smarty3

Is the following acceptable, even if `$my_flag` may not be set?

```
{if ( $my_flag )}
    // Vrooom
{/if}
```

Do I always need `isset` to ensure notices aren't thrown, or does Smarty3 take care of things?

Comment: Yes, and all seems well. I'm more concerned that when the template is compiled, I want to be sure the corresponding PHP won't throw errors with `E_STRICT`

Answer (score 0):

It is acceptable, but PHP will warn you that `$my_flag` is undefined.

I would do something like that:

```
{if isset($my_flag)}
    {if $my_flag == 123}
        <p>print something</p>
    {/if}
{/if}
```

If you will try your current script everything will work, but it will log a notice. The above script makes sure the only if the variable is set then do something.

However, since Smarty is cached you may have to reload the page a few times to see the changes (unless you specify `$smarty_obj->force_compile = true;`).